# Does .Net support curried generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, currying

Suppose we have a nested generic class:

```
public class A<T> {
    public class B<U> { }
}
```

Here, `typeof(A<int>.B<>)` is in essence a generic class with two parameters where only the first is bound.

If I have a single class with two parameters

```
public class AB<T, U> { }
```

Is there a way to refer to "`AB` with `T=int` and `U` staying open"? If not, is this a C# limitation, or a CLR limitation?

Comment: Can this be done with types in F#?

Comment: If you're asking me, I have no idea... I've never actually used F# for any length of time.

Comment: By "curried", you mean "partially closed"?

Comment: Following up by Googling, i found this blog post: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/01/partially-closed-generic-types/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it can't be done in C#, you have to specify either both type parameters, or none.

And it doesn't seem to be supported by the CLR either, `A<int>.B<>` and `A<string>.B<>` refer to the same type:

```
Type t1 = typeof(A<int>).GetNestedType("B`1");
Type t2 = typeof(A<string>).GetNestedType("B`1");
// t1.Equals(t2) is true
```

The enclosing type of both types is `A<>` (open generic type)

EDIT: further testing shows that `typeof(A<int>.B<string>)` is actually a generic type of arity 2, *not* a nested generic type of arity 1... `typeof(A<int>.B<string>).GetGenericArguments()` returns an array with `typeof(int)` *and* `typeof(string)`. So `typeof(A<int>.B<>)` would actually be equivalent to `(A.B)<int, >`, which isn't supported (a generic type can't be partially closed)

Comment: Your observation is correct. Under the covers, C<T>.D<U> is just "C.D"<T, U>. The C# way of conceiving of it as C<T>.D<U> is just a convenient fiction.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for the confirmation. I was hoping you would see this question and shed some light on it... It could be a good subject for a blog post if you're out of ideas ;)

Comment: You're right, of course. My mistake was assuming that `typeof(A<int>.B<>)` would be legal - I knew that `A<T>.B<U>` is implemented as `A.B<T, U>`, meaning that `typeof(A<int>.B<>)` would actually be `A.B<int, >` which didn't seem like it should be legal.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
   class AB<T, U>
   {
      protected T t;
      U u;
   }

   class C<U> : AB<int, U>
   {
      public void Foo()
      {
         t = 5;
      }
   }
```

Comment: @downvoter: talk to me.  Would you like to see reflector output, C# specification excerpt, something else?

Comment: It looks like the OP is asking for an instance of a `Type` object that expresses something like `typeof(AB<int,>)`.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the Func<int,int> generic to pass multiple parameters as a single function returning an type. Curried many to pass many arguments as a single parameter.

```
 [Fact]
    public async Task TestCurried()
    {
        Func<int, Func<int, int>> curried = x => y => x + y;
        int sum = curried(1)(3);
        Assert.Equal(sum.ToString(), "4");
    }
see
https://blog.tchatzigiannakis.com/generics-as-super-functions/
```